# Incoming TCP raw socket in Windows is not received

Tags: tcp, raw-sockets

I'm trying to send a SYN packet that has been received in one network interface into another one on the same host (while changing the IP addresses), using a raw socket.

I'm on Windows Server 2008 R2, and while sending and receiving UDP packets is going very well, when I'm trying to send a TCP packet, the other side just not receiving it (although it shown correctly in Wireshark). The other side normally listens to SOCK_STREAM data.

I've just read in [this](https://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/) site that:

> Even though you can send TCP packets with a raw socket, the operating system's TCP/IP stack will process incoming TCP and UDP packets. When you send a TCP SYN packet with a raw socket, the destination's response will be rejected by the operating system because it is unaware of the SYN you sent. Therefore, you cannot complete a three-way handshake.

However, Microsoft [noted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85%29.aspx) that:

> These above restrictions do not apply to **Windows Server 2008 R2**, Windows Server 2008 , Windows Server 2003, or to versions of the operating system earlier than Windows XP with SP2.

Is it that TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets? However, if yes, is there a way to establish the TCP connection anyway? Maybe some WinAPI to add the stream identifier?

I'd love to hear any solution for establishing TCP connections with a raw socket. Thanks!

Comment: When you say that the packet is shown correctly in wireshark, which machine to you mean? The sender or the receiver?

Comment: I'm sending to another interface in the same machine, and capturing on the destination one.

Comment: I see. does the destination interface (and the regular socket bound to it) respond to regular (non-raw) TCP Syns? If you telnet to the destination socket from the source interface, do you see a three way handshake?

Comment: Well, if both Syns come from the same source interface (and same IP), and arrive at the same destination, and one gets a syn-ack response while the other doesn't then there has to be something wrong with the syn... Could you post a capture of both cases?

Comment: The SYNs are the same in both cases. However, I think the problem is somewhere in the mechanism the operating system adds the TCP sessions to it's lists. In the case of regular TCP SOCK_STREAM its probably inserts the sequence number or the connection information in some kernel memory, and in the raw socket not - and when the listener sees that it's from a local interface but bot in that memory, it avoids it.

Comment: If I understand the situation correctly, that doesn't make sense for one simple reason: Say the sender was a different machine that would send two TCP Syns - one using a regular socket, and one using a raw socket. If both syns are well formed, they look identical to the receiver, so it would respond to both with a synack.
A situation similar to what you're suggesting could happen if the RECEIVING socket is RAW. In case of a raw listening socket, the OS doesn't keep any information about received packets and sequence numbers, and doesn't respond to handshake attempts.